# How to find out what is triggering an htaccess popup?

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, resources

When loading a page of my site I see a htaccess password popup. If I click cancel 2 or 3 times the page loads fine, so it must be one of the resources.

How can I find out which resource is triggering the password pop-up? This is annoying our customers ...

One important point: I only see the popup in Internet Explorer! There is no password when using firefox, safari, chrome...

Comment: I think I found my answer: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

Let us know what your answer is. I think it has to do with permissions  of some resource your file or file's are loading.

Comment: I used fiddler to see which file was accessing a protected resource